# remove product in cart laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I try to develop shopping cart using laravel and I use laravel shopping cart in this [link](https://github.com/bumbummen99/LaravelShoppingcart) my problem is I cannot remove product in cart and will get this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6jZf.png)

web.php

```
Route::post('/cart/{rowId}', 'CartController@destroy')->name('cart.destroy');
```

CartController.php

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    \Cart::remove($id);
    return back()->with('success', 'Item has been removed!');
}
```

index.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.destroy', $item->rowId) }}" method="POST">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Remove</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is the problem but in your destroy controller you should `return redirect->back()->with(...)`

Comment: I get this URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/cart/{rowId}', 'CartController@destroy')->name('cart.destroy');
```

**CartController.php**

```
public function destroy($id) {
    $cart = Cart::findOrFail($id);
    $cart->delete();

    return redirect()->route('')->with('success', 'Item has been removed!');
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<a href="{{ route('cart.destroy', $item->rowId) }}" class="" title="Remove Cart">
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: I get the same URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da still cannot remove product on cart

Comment: In place of `return back()->with();` use `return redirect()->route('')->with('');`

Comment: Inside `route()` define your route